# Android studio profiler: Selected region does not have full tracking

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling, tracking

When profiling memory with Android Studio 4.1, I get "Selected region does not have full tracking" as a warning. How can I turn on full tracking?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the allocation tracking from the default "Sampled" to "Full" by selecting "Full" from the [allocation tracking dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n0uG.png).

Full allocation tracking can have a significant performance impact on your application if the application is making 1000's of allocations per second.